# How to detect hosts on the local network running the Java program for a specified port address?

Tags: java, network-programming

I am working on a project in which I need to retrieve a list of hosts on the local network which are running a Java application on a pre-specified port (e.g. port 55283)
Also, any way through which the MAC address of the host can be found?
I am currently using sockets in my project (using JDK 7)
Any external library or API that I should see? Kindly provide any other source.

Comment: have u tried something??

Comment: initially i was trying the brute force method... by pinging all the available computers on the network. But as you can guess... it turned out to be a really bad way

Comment: have you tried the below answer??

Comment: i then started to look around a way to include results from a cmd query into the java... i did a multicast ping on my network and then used the arp command "arp -a" to get all the available computers online along with their mac addresses. But I have no idea how to use the result into my java program. Any way through which I can use a cmd query in my Java program

Comment: I am going to try it now :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then execute command `net view` using `Process` in java

it will give you the output like

> C:\Users\NiRRaNjAN>net view
>
> Server Name            Remark
>
> ---
>
> \NIRRANJAN-PC
>
> The command completed successfully.

parse these lines and you will get the names of online machines in given network. After that get the ip address of machines using `InetAddress.getByName("host").getHostAddress();` method. Here is sample code for that..

```
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec("net view\n");
            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                if(line.isEmpty()) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    continue;
                }
                contents.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            String[] ips = contents.toString().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            ArrayList<String> networkIPs = new ArrayList<>();
            if(ips.length >= 3) {
                for(int i=2;i<ips.length-1;i++) {
                    if(ips[i].isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    networkIPs.add(InetAddress.getByName(ips[i].replaceAll("\\\\", "").trim()).getHostAddress());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(networkIPs);
```

after that you can check if ports are open or not by connect to these IPs using `Socket`...

Comment: whats wrong with the answer???? isn't it working??

Comment: I haven't tried the solution yet. I have not rated this answer till now.